# Xpath Extractor is not returning value in Jmeter

Tags: xpath, jmeter

I wanted to extract the value from the below HTML.

```
<input type="hidden" value="09a02539-e89c-4118-bc52-185330ef36e4" name="AUTH_STATE">

$x("//input[@name='AUTH_STATE']") Tried this command in Console and it returns ( )
```

I have used /html/body/div/div[2]/div/form/input (xpath returned by firebug) and //input[@name='AUTH_STATE'] both returns the below failure in JMETER

```
Assertion error: false
Assertion failure: true
Assertion failure message: The reference to entity "scope" must end with the ';' delimiter.
See log file for further details.
```

[image]

I have tried with and without";" I need to extract the value field from the above HTML.. How to resolve this??

Comment: In results tree, look at the sample response and use XPath tester there to play around with your XPath query.

Comment: Exception:org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 35; columnNumber: 134; The reference to entity "scope" must end with the ';' delimiter.

Comment: I have tried xpath tester in View Results Tree, it returns above exception. But when i give XML format, i am able to locate AUTH_STATE in response of login GET call..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through XPATH extractor, if i use this i am getting the values..

```
//*[@name='AUTH_STATE']/@value
```

Through RegEx Extractor. getting the values

```
 .AUTH_STATE" value="(.+?)".
```

Answer (score 2):

1. If response is not XML/HTXML-compliant check `Use Tidy` box elsewise XPath extraction will fail
2. Check whether this `AUTH_STATE` bit is returned by "Main sample". In some cases there is a redirect from first request and interesting values are living on child samples - so double-check correct "Scope"
3. Use XPath query which is not sensitive to DOM changes. In your case the good one will be

   ```
   //input[@name='AUTH_STATE']/@value
   ```
4. For more information see [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) guide.

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular Expression extractor instead:

***.value="(.+?)" name="AUTH_STATE".***

Match count: 1
Match[1][0]= value="09a02539-e89c-4118-bc52-185330ef36e4" name="AUTH_STATE">
Match[1][1]=09a02539-e89c-4118-bc52-185330ef36e4

hope this will help.